# Error: variable digitMonth might not have been initialized

Tags: java, if-statement, initialization

I'm trying to write a program that takes a birth year, month, and day and calculates what day said birthday that lies on. Thing is, I get this error message:

error: variable digitMonth might not have been initialized
        total = inputYear + test2 + digitMonth + inputDay;
                                    ^

I don't know how to fix it. Setting digitMonth to a number (e.g. 1)makes the program work, but for the formula, each month requires a different number (1 for January, 4, for February, 4 for March, 0 for April, etc)

I've looked at the other questions for errors like this and I haven't found anything useful yet.

Help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Birth{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inputYear, inputMonth, inputDay, digitMonth, test2, total, dayNum;

    System.out.println("Enter the last two digits of the year that you were born in");
    inputYear = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the month number that your were born in");
    inputMonth = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your birth day");
    inputDay = scan.nextInt();

    test2 = inputYear / 4;

    if (inputMonth > 0 && inputMonth < 2)
    {
        digitMonth = 1;
    }
    else if (inputMonth > 1 && inputMonth < 3)
    {
            digitMonth = 4;
    }
    else if (inputMonth > 2 && inputMonth < 4)
    {
            digitMonth = 4;
    }
    else if (inputMonth > 3 && inputMonth < 5)
    {
            digitMonth = 0;
    }
    else if (inputMonth > 4 && inputMonth < 6)
    {
            digitMonth = 2;
    }
    else if (inputMonth > 5 && inputMonth < 7)
    {
            digitMonth = 5;
    }
    else if (inputMonth > 6 && inputMonth < 8)
    {
            digitMonth = 0;
    }
    else if (inputMonth > 7 && inputMonth < 9)
    {
            digitMonth = 3;
    }
    else if (inputMonth > 8 && inputMonth < 10)
    {
            digitMonth = 6;
    }
    else if (inputMonth > 9 && inputMonth < 11)
    {
            digitMonth = 1;
    }
    else if (inputMonth > 10 && inputMonth < 12)
    {
            digitMonth = 4;
    }
    else if (inputMonth > 11 && inputMonth < 13)
    {
            digitMonth = 6;
    }
    else
        System.out.println("You fuck-up");


    total = inputYear + test2 + digitMonth + inputDay;
    dayNum = total / 7;

    if (dayNum > 0 || dayNum < 2)
    {
        System.out.println("You were born on a Sunday");
    }
    else if (dayNum > 1 || dayNum < 3)
    {
        System.out.println("You were born on a Monday");
    }
    else if (dayNum > 2 || dayNum < 4)
    {
        System.out.println("You were born on a Tuesday");
    }
    else if (dayNum > 3 || dayNum < 5)
    {
        System.out.println("You were born on a Wednesday");
    }
    else if (dayNum > 4 || dayNum < 6)
    {
        System.out.println("You were born on a Thursday");
    }
    else if (dayNum > 5 || dayNum < 7)
    {
        System.out.println("You were born on a Friday");
    }
    else if (dayNum > -1 || dayNum < 1)
    {
        System.out.println("You were born on a Saturday");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you using `inputMonth > 0 && inputMonth < 2` instead of `inputMonth == 1`? (Which will easily let you translate the `if` to `switch` as a bonus).

Comment: You use `digitMonth` before Java can be *100% sure* that it's been initialized. Either set `digitMonth` in the `else` branch, or exit the method. (or assign a default value to `digitMonth`)

Answer (score 1):

You only assign a value to `digitMonth` inside the `if` and `else if` statements and not on the final `else` statement.
So what happenes if none of `if` and `else if` succeeds and only the `else` part does? 
 The
What will be the value of `digitMonth` then ?
 
**Answer:** None 
This may never happen in your code but nevertheless the compiler complains about it. 
There are 2 solutions:

**1)** Just give an initial value to `digitMonth`. i.e. `int digitMonth = 0;`

**2)** Initialize `digitMonth` inside the final else. i.e:

```
else{
    //some code
    digitMonth = 0;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it's a possibility that `digitMonth` is used before a value is assigned to it. One option is to set `digitMonth` to a default value:

```
int digitMonth = 0;
```

Another alternative is to assign a value to `digitMonth` in the `else` branch:

```
...
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid month");
    digitMonth = 0;
}
```

You could also stop the control flow in the `else` branch:

```
...
else {
    return;
    // OR throw a RuntimeException 
    // throw new IllegalArgumentException
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize `digitMonth` to `zero` as well
I think there is incorrect logic in your code too:

you should have : `dayNum = total % 7;`

Hope the following code works fine:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputYear, inputMonth, inputDay, digitMonth = 0, test2, total, dayNum;

        System.out.println("Enter the last two digits of the year that you were born in");
        inputYear = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the month number that your were born in");
        inputMonth = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your birth day");
        inputDay = scan.nextInt();

        test2 = inputYear / 4;

        if (inputMonth > 0 && inputMonth < 2)
        {
            digitMonth = 1;
        }
        else if (inputMonth > 1 && inputMonth < 3)
        {
                digitMonth = 4;
        }
        else if (inputMonth > 2 && inputMonth < 4)
        {
                digitMonth = 4;
        }
        else if (inputMonth > 3 && inputMonth < 5)
        {
                digitMonth = 0;
        }
        else if (inputMonth > 4 && inputMonth < 6)
        {
                digitMonth = 2;
        }
        else if (inputMonth > 5 && inputMonth < 7)
        {
                digitMonth = 5;
        }
        else if (inputMonth > 6 && inputMonth < 8)
        {
                digitMonth = 0;
        }
        else if (inputMonth > 7 && inputMonth < 9)
        {
                digitMonth = 3;
        }
        else if (inputMonth > 8 && inputMonth < 10)
        {
                digitMonth = 6;
        }
        else if (inputMonth > 9 && inputMonth < 11)
        {
                digitMonth = 1;
        }
        else if (inputMonth > 10 && inputMonth < 12)
        {
                digitMonth = 4;
        }
        else if (inputMonth > 11 && inputMonth < 13)
        {
                digitMonth = 6;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("You fuck-up");


        total = inputYear + test2 + digitMonth + inputDay;
        dayNum = total % 7;

        switch(dayNum){
        case 1:System.out.println("You were born on a Sunday");break;
        case 2:System.out.println("You were born on a Monday");break;
        case 3: System.out.println("You were born on a Tuesday");break;
        case 4:System.out.println("You were born on a Wednesday");break;
        case 5:System.out.println("You were born on a Thursday");break;
        case 6:System.out.println("You were born on a Friday");break;
        case 7:System.out.println("You were born on a Saturday");break;

        }
```